# Display long text in UI-GRID column without ellipse

Tags: angular-ui-grid

In my application, I'm using ui-grid to display two column: name and description.
Description column can have around 500char. Currently ui-grid is trimming the description text using "ellipse". I want whole description should be displayed in a single line. I dont mind if horizontal scrollbar come. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "width" parameter in your columnDefs.

`$scope.myGrid.columnDefs = [
    { name:'name', width: 100},
    { name:'description', width: 1000}
 ];`

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_width

EDIT : You can try adding up the "width: '*'" option. I know it didn't work for me, on my side, but I am not using the most up-to-date version of UI-Grid, so it might only work on a more recent version than the one I use.

Comment: I don't know how long the text will be. So I can't assign any specific value to the width. I need width to be dynamic say width:auto